# How to complie smart contract in node.js [solc version: ^0.8.13]

Tags: solidity, solc, compiler

I would like to complie my smart contract code at node.js. Although solc version at package.json and solidity version at smart contract code are same, it doesn't work.

complie.js

```
const path= require('path');
const solc = require('solc');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

const builtPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
//remove file in build module
fs.removeSync(builtPath);
const bettingPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts','Betting.sol');
//read  content present in file
console.log(bettingPath);
const source = fs.readFileSync(bettingPath, 'utf8');
//compile contract
const output = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts;
//create build folder

fs.ensureDirSync(builtPath);
console.log(output);


for(let contract in output)
{
    fs.outputJsonSync(
        path.resolve(buildPath, contract.replace(':','')+ '.json'),
        output[contract]
    );
}
```

package.json

```
{
"name": "smart_betting",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "dev": "node server.js"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
  "@truffle/hdwallet-provider": "^2.0.4",
  "fs-extra": "^10.0.1",
  "ganache-cli": "^6.12.2",
  "mocha": "^9.2.2",
  "next": "^12.1.0",
  "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
  "react": "^17.0.2",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
  "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
  "semantic-ui-react": "^2.1.2",
  "solc": "^0.8.13",
  "web3": "^1.7.1"
}
}
```

At top of Betting.sol, `pragma solidity ^0.8.13;`

When I'm trying to complie by `node complie.js`
it returns error like below.

```
/Users/mac/BlockchainProjects/smartBetting/ethereum/contracts/Betting.sol
node:assert:399
    throw err;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid callback object specified.
    at runWithCallbacks      (/Users/mac/BlockchainProjects/smartBetting/node_modules/solc/wrapper.js:117:34)
at compileStandard (/Users/mac/BlockchainProjects/smartBetting/node_modules/solc/wrapper.js:223:20)
at Object.compileStandardWrapper [as compile] (/Users/mac/BlockchainProjects/smartBetting/node_modules/solc/wrapper.js:229:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mac/BlockchainProjects/smartBetting/ethereum/compile.js:13:21)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='
}
```

Comment: you can visit this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53353167/npm-solc-assertionerror-err-assertion-invalid-callback-specified
it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

The version starting 0.6.0 of solidiity have changes, follow a [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js#example-usage-without-the-import-callback) you can see how to work with this.

So, this work for me.

```
const path= require('path');
const solc = require('solc');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

const builtPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
//remove file in build module
fs.removeSync(builtPath);
const bettingPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts','Betting.sol');
//read  content present in file
console.log(bettingPath);
const source = fs.readFileSync(bettingPath, 'utf8');

const input = {
  language: 'Solidity',
  sources: {
    'Betting.sol': {
      content: source,
    },
  },
  settings: {
    outputSelection: {
      '*': {
        '*': ['*']
      }
    }
  }
};

//compile contract
var output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));

//create build folder
fs.ensureDirSync(builtPath);
console.log(output);

for(let contract in output.contracts['Betting.sol']){
  fs.outputJsonSync(
      path.resolve(buildPath, contract + '.json'),
      output.contracts['Betting.sol'][contract].evm
  );
}
```